# How This React Hook i.e useEffect is re-rendering even if the second argument being passed is an empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```
  function WindowSizeList() {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)

  const updateWindowWidth = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>Window Width: {windowWidth}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

This component renders window width when mounted for first time for which useEffect() runs, Ok... then when the browser window is resized the `window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)` runs inside the useEffect()

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)
  }, [])
```

and then it triggers

```
  const updateWindowWidth = () => {
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
  }
```

for which the component re-renders with the state change of `windowWidth` and also renders that value in the component, Ok...But when I again resize the browser window, how come the process is repeated i.e useEffect is re-running and then updating the value in DOM even thought it should run once as I have used empty second argument `[]` in

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)
  }, [])
```

Comment: Where did you get that process in `useEffect`
repeats?

Comment: You never detach the event listener. That's probably what's running?

Comment: The `useEffect` is only running once but your event listener still exists and is calling the `setWindowWidth` function which changes your state variable and causes the re-render. Return a cleanup function from `useEffect` that removes the event listener

Comment: @AbirTaheer Well, why to use cleanup function if the useEffect runs only once when it is mounted. (Maybe a silly question but I am learning React for the first time so....).

Comment: @AbirTaheer Means, even if I use cleanup function I still don't understand how come the event listener is still existing, doing all this things again and again when i resize DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
 function WindowSizeList() {
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(YourInitialValue)

 useEffect(() => {
    // Define your handler 
    function updateWindowWidth(){
    setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth)
    }
    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
       updateWindowWidth()
    // Remove event listener on cleanup
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", updateWindowWidth);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount


  return (
    <>
      <div>Window Width: {windowWidth}</div>
    </>
  )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

An eventlistener is attached once only and keeps running until you remove them or reload the page.

```
// Attach an event handler to <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").addEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth);
```

```
// Remove the event handler from <div>
document.getElementById("myDIV").removeEventListener('resize', updateWindowWidth)
```

For better understanding you can read event loop in JavaScript.